# how to draw 3D Cartesian system in android and openGL

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have drawn some 3D structure in android suing openGL (GL10). Now I want to show them on 3D cartesian system. Can you suggest me how to do this.

for reference: how it this cartesian system should work: 
http://hotmath.com/learning_activities/interactivities/3dplotter.swf

Comment: You want to draw the axis of the cartesian system? Or is it something else that you want? (sorry I can't read your 3dplotter.swf)

Comment: yes. Axis for cartesian system and rotate it. if not difficult then to make planes also.